# Magento site shows error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 Out of memory

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, database, error, mysql, mysql-config

One of our store show following error and stop working at all.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 Out of memory
```

and Mysql / Innodb Error

```
InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is 943460

[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 27262948 bytes)
```

Why Magento showing goes down and show this error?

More details (if needed):

At that time error occur online user were 150.

My.ini settings related to innodb are

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
query_cache_limit =500M
query_cache_size = 96M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
key_buffer = 512M 
max_allowed_packet = 64M
table_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
query_cache_type = 1
max_connections=500
wait_timeout=120
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
set-variable = max_connections=500
```

Server:

```
CPU: inter quad core 
memory: 4GB
disk: 100GB

OS centOS 6.3
Apache 2.0
PHP 5.3
Mysql 5.0
```

PS.

As per error ie. trying insert too much data into InnoDB too quickly.

log_visitor_info, log_url_info and log_url are much overwritten.

What if I will change log_visitor_info, log_url_info and log_url storage engine to myISAM will it solve this problem?

is it ok changing of storage engine of these tables?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: and your server specs?

Comment: I updated server specs in question.
Let us know if anything missed

Comment: `memory: 4GB` vs input your variables in http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/ and you will see why you get that error.

Comment: Thanks FlorinelChis,

It seems I need more than 8 Gb memory for this.
How I can optimize MySql for 4GB memory as it unable to handle magento?

Comment: Problem updated requesting your attention..

Comment: Not a Magento error, your MySQL server needs configuration optimization to handle the load, or you're on an inadequate server such as shared hosting where your doled out resources aren't enough to allow MySQL to run. Default MySQL install configurations are just asking for data corruption when you're running Magento on top of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a sql buffer size issue.

Review your query, increase buffers in my.ini. Also make sure to repair all your tables and re-index them.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html